# How to send a message consumed by a queue to an express app?

Tags: node.js, express, amqp

So I have a simple get method in an express app that sends a message to a queue, using the [amqp library](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node)

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    sendMessageToQueue('messageSent', 'producerQueue');
    res.send('messageReceivedFromQueue');
})
```

Where [sendMessageToQueue](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/send.js) is:

```
function sendMessageToQueue(msg, q) {
    amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
        return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {

          var ok = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

          return ok.then(function(_qok) {
              ch.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(msg));
              console.log(" [-] Sent '%s' to", msg, q);
              return ch.close();
          });
        }).finally(function() { conn.close();});
    }).catch(console.warn);
}
```

And the correspondent [receive](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/receive.js) function

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
      var q = 'consumerQueue';

      var ok = ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});

      ok = ok.then(function(_qok) {
        return ch.consume(q, consumeMessageFromQueue, {noAck: true});
      });

      return ok.then(function(_consumeOk) {
        console.log(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C');
      });
    });
  }).catch(console.warn);
```

Where consumeMessageFromQueue is:

```
function consumeMessageFromQueue(msg) {
    console.log(" [+] Received '%s'", msg.content.toString());
}
```

---

How can I send the message from the ***consumeMessageFromQueue*** function instead of the hardcoded '*messageReceivedFromQueue*' string inside the app.get function?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to use `res.send` inside the consumeMessageFromQueue function and pass it the `msg` parameter?

Comment: Yes, that would be one approach. (other would be to get somehow the `msg` from the `consumeMessageFromQueue` function and pass it to the `app.get` function)

Comment: The point of a queue is that things happen async, meaning you can reply to the client before anything in the queue has been consumed and processed. It feels like you're attempting some sort of anti-pattern. That said you could use a closure to do it, though I'd advise against it!

Comment: Do you think it would be better to use two separate `app` methods? (one for sending the message and another one for consuming it)

Comment: Generally you would create an endpoint which would do something (such as creating a social media post). This would attach the post onto a queue and return to the client a 200 OK. The queue is free to be processed however it likes and at any speed after that. At any point the user can then request a different endpoint without waiting for the queue to process. In our social media instance, if they requested their timeline, the status may not appear immediately as it may not have been processed yet. That is then down to scaling your consuming workers.

Comment: So in essence, I'm wondering why you need data from the queue within the same request? It seems to defeat the point of queuing the request at all.

Comment: So I'm sending a message to a `producerQueue`, which is sent forward to another service and then the service will respond to this message with another message on a `consumerQueue` which I'd want to send to the client. You're saying that I should use another request for sending the message received from the consumer queue? (or maybe you'd like to suggest a different approach for achieving this)

Comment: Yes I am saying you shouldn't hold up a HTTP request for something that is sitting in a queue system. Queues are meant to decouple services and allow long running background processes. If you want to dispatch something to another service and have it processed _synchronously_ then don't use a queue, just send the request to the second service and await the response. Otherwise your queue is essentially useless. If your worker process dies or has a lot of load, your HTTP requests from the first service are likely to timeout.